# Hiding prices from certain countries using GeoIP

Tags: store-view, stores

My website is going to be viewed worldwide, but I want only certain countries to be able to view prices/purchase goods.

In total there will be 5 different regions that will be able to view prices/buy products, but the product ranges will vary depending on region.

I thought about using GeoIP to determine where the customer is based, but how do I do this using different stores/store views?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The principle is fairly simple, you can just add the appropriate logic into your `.htaccess` file or into the `index.php` file. You need only set the environment variables for the store/website so that Magento can load the appropriate one.

The environment variables are,

- `MAGE_RUN_CODE` - Whatever you set as the store/website code in your admin
- `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` - Either website or store depending on the scope of the code you are trying to load

If you are using Apache, you could use mod_geoip2; Nginx, recompile with the geoip module; MageStack, use the existing `GEO_` environment variables; if anything else, you could load the PHP PECL extension for geoip.

Then its just a case of using a simple setenvif, set or conditional statement to set the appropriate code/type.